# Reload bxSlider when revealing previously hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

bxSlider has a function to reload slider(s) at a specific action. I initialise multiple sliders on my page in the following way:

```
jQuery('.product_carousel_images').each(function(index,item) {

    jQuery(item).bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        speed: 600,
        pause: 7000,
        auto: false,
        controls: false,
        pager: true,
        pagerCustom: '.product_carousel_pager'
    });

});
```

Using jQuery easytabs for a tab layout, the first slider is in the first (i.e. visible) tab and working well, while the second is generated in an initially hidden div. Since bxSlider sets the height of a slider within a div with display:none to 0, the second slider has zero-height images. visibility:hidden isn't an option, since the tabs interface doesn't allow for that.
With this multiple slider function, how can I trigger a reload of my sliders on a specific action, like clicking a tab header?

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS `.bx-viewport {min-height:90vh;}` adjust according to needs.

Comment: @zer00ne Unfortunately, it's not that easy :(. On large screens, the height is messing up being enormous (due to 90% of viewport), on smaller it might work better, but setting the viewport height as a condition can only possibly cause problems, right?

Comment: Adjust according to needs, the point is if you set a `min-height` on `.bx-viewport`, bxSlider will honor that height. That goes for when it loads, reloads, resizes, etc. If you set it to a small size say 200px and it originally was going to be 0, it will be 200px for a second and then expand to it's content height.

Comment: Well, since the site is responsive, I don't have a fixed height/min-height I could assign natively. And unfortunately, bxslider accepts the min-height, but wouldn't expand. I believe the inline CSS rules are applied when the page loads, and since then has e.g. 200px in height given via CSS, it doesn't look further and applies its width accordingly.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I remember you, your'e the one that fixates on something and can't see the other side of things. I'll take my code elsewhere.

Comment: To sum it up: I set a small `min-height` to `.bx-slider` and tried around different values in px, vh and %, and still bxSlider unfortunately does not set it to the min-height for a second and then expands to its content's height on load in a hidden div, it stays on the min-height value I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use bxSlider myself, however I'm guessing you can make use of bxSlider's "reloadSlider" function.

http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider

Just keep a reference to your slider at initialization, then call reloadSlider on it whenever you change tabs, which in your case with easy tabs would have to make use of the easytabs:after event.

```
var slider = jQuery(item).bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    speed: 600,
    pause: 7000,
    auto: false,
    controls: false,
    pager: true,
    pagerCustom: '.product_carousel_pager'
});
// Reload slider whenever tab changes
$('#your-tabs-container').bind('easytabs:after', function() {
    // TODO identify the displayed tab using EasyTabs target panel parameters in order not to reload bxSlider when the wrong tab is displayed
    slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

More information on EasyTabs' Event Hooks here: 
https://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#configuration

Comment: Well, I was down that road already, but still it doesn't actually reload the carousels. I believe it is due to the each function, since I have a carousel on the first and the last tab. I use a class .tabs for the carousel containers instead of an ID.

Comment: You would indeed have to keep a reference for each slider and reload each of them